# change linq query to give best perfomance

Tags: c#, linq

I am working on a performance improvement task to optimize the LINQ-SQL query logic.
  Can someone suggest the best optimized query . Here is my query

```
var localResponse = (from p in context.Places                                 
                     where (p.PlaceName.Contains(searchText))
                         && (p.MkTypeId == MkType.Premise)
                         && p.PlaceName != null
                         && p.ObjectState != ObjectState.Deleted
                     select new Prediction {
                                    value = p.PlaceName,
                                    id = p.APIPlaceId,
                                    reference = p.APIPlaceReference,
                                    latitude = p.Location.Latitude,
                                    longitude = p.Location.Longitude,
                                    addressId = p.AddressId,
                                    bedroom = p.Bedroom,
                                    placeTypeId = p.PlaceTypeId,
                                    placeId = p.Id
                             })
                     .Union(from p in context.Places
                            join cp in context.Places on p.Id equals cp.ParentPlaceId
                            where (p.PlaceName.Contains(searchText) || cp.PlaceName.Contains(searchText))
                                && (p.MkTypeId == MkType.Premise || p.MkTypeId == MkType.Room)
                                && p.PlaceName != null
                                && cp.PlaceName != null
                                && p.ObjectState != ObjectState.Deleted
                                && cp.ObjectState != ObjectState.Deleted
                            select new Prediction {
                                           value = cp.PlaceName + ", " + p.PlaceName,
                                           id = p.APIPlaceId,
                                           reference = p.APIPlaceReference,
                                           latitude = p.Location.Latitude,
                                           longitude = p.Location.Longitude,
                                           addressId = p.AddressId,
                                           bedroom = p.Bedroom,
                                           placeTypeId = p.PlaceTypeId,
                                           placeId = p.Id  });
```

Here is Prediction Class

```
 public class Prediction
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string reference { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public double? latitude { get; set; }
    public double? longitude { get; set; }
    public int? addressId { get; set; }
    public int? bedroom { get; set; }
    public PlaceType placeTypeId { get; set; }
    public int? placeId { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what rdp are you using entityframwork

Comment: Optimized for what? If you want to optimize something, you _must_ state a goal...

Comment: sometimes it's better to split query to shorter ones, surely they will be more readable

Comment: @COLDTOLD yes we are using entity framework

Comment: to be honest for a query that big the best way to do it is just to use raw sql that will get you the best performance or just write sproc http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx

Comment: @JeffMercado My Goal is simple its now taking 10-12 seconds i want this time tobe 1 or 2 second

Comment: You can only do so much from here. An optimal query here will do nothing here in terms of speed if you don't optimize how your databases are structured (e.g., having plenty of memory, set up indexes where appropriate, better table structure, etc.) or have better control over the size and amount of data you want to query. You should look at other ways you can optimize the database side first before you start worrying about how you query it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to avoid the UNION statement by performing an left outer join on Places and ParentPlaces. Beside this, the main issue to your query is the expression "Contains(SearchText)". It forces all remaining records (not deleted and PlaceName not empty) to be iterated one by one in a sequential scan (scanning all records). This is subject to a fulltext search. So please try to find out if your database supports such a feature.